# Android Studio website

Tags: android, android-studio

This is a quite strange question: why some parts of the android studio wesite aren't written in English but in Japanese?

[image]

and why Android Studio on startup tells me that there is an update available but if I visit the official website and start the download it is downloaded a less recent version than the one installed on my computer?

Vesrion installed: `android-studio-bundle-141.2343393-windows`

Version available for download on http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/sdk/index.html#top:
`android-studio-bundle-141.2288178-windows.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, it's probably because you're on the Japanese website. The English one / official one is here :  http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

For the version, it's not important. With the new intellij/android studio, update come through the software.

Comment: Ok, finally I solved: your link redirects to the same page: [http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/sdk/index.html](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/sdk/index.html) but then I have replaced "/ja/" with "/en/" and now it always shows me the english page. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it was that (sorry, I explained it bad)